# Measurability in a product space of a set defined only along its fibers

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$. Then, using Kolmogorov extension theorem, I can consider  the probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega:= [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\mathbb{P}=\lambda^{\otimes\mathbb{N}} $ denotes the Kolmogorov extension of the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$ and $\Sigma$  is the product sigma algebra obtained again by Kolmogorov extension theorem.

Consider also the probability space $(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{S}^1),\lambda_{\mathbb{S}^1})$, where again $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\lambda_{\mathbb{S}^1}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in the circle.
Now consider  the product space $(\Omega \times \mathbb{S}^1,\Sigma\times\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{S}^1), \mathbb{P}\times \lambda_{\mathbb{S}^1})$.

Suppose that there exists  a set $\tilde{\Omega} \subset \Omega$ with full  $\mathbb{P}$ measure  such for all $\omega \in \tilde{\Omega}$, there is a set   $I(\omega)\subset \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$, which is a finite union of disjoint intervals, and this choice of intervals depends on $\omega$.

My question is: is the set

$$\bigcup_{\omega \in \tilde{\Omega}} \{\omega\} \times I(\omega)$$

measurable with respect to $\Sigma\times\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

Comment: For singletons $I(\omega)=\{f(\omega)\}$ (and $\tilde\Omega=\Omega$) your set is the graph of an arbitrary function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb S^1$ which need not be measurable.